# Build locally and the output to docker image vs Build while creating docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I hava java application which needs to be dockerized now and I have 2 options.

1. Build locally and add the jar generated at target folder to docker image.
2. Build it while creating the image. like,

```
    FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder

    COPY propel_settings_local.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml

    RUN mkdir -p /build

    ADD . /build/
    WORKDIR /build

    RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins

    RUN mvn clean install
```

Which is better approach among these two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options seems fine but I will say it totaly depend on your case but you can consider some of them below.

> Build locally and add the jar generated at target folder to docker
>   image.

- This option suit when you are working on a local machine and need a frequent build and update of the image.
- For that, you also need a proper local environment which is able to generate the jar
- The developer also needs to set up a local java environment, in short for development copying build and mounting jar file with the container is fine to go with this approach.

> Build it while creating the image.

- This approach is good for CI/CD but follow the [multi-stage](https://gist.github.com/liemle3893/025624fc02dbecc0e8fd99a40a4ae94c) to keep your docker image small or also you can check @Tushar Answer.
- With this approach, your developer does not need to have Java Environment on the local system

Further, you can explore [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) and [7-best-practices-for-building-containers](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/7-best-practices-for-building-containers) for your self.

Answer (score 1):

I have springboot applications and have been following multi-stage build concept of docker

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 as builder

WORKDIR chooseTheOneYouWant

COPY . .  ( i.e. copy whole of your code into the work directory)

RUN mvn -B package

FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir /usr/app

COPY --from=build .jarFile /usr/app

WORKDIR /usr/app

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/app/.jarFile"]
```